# VBA | Trying to get matching values to have specific outputs in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script that does three things. Finds all cells in a range that have a "x" in them, then takes those cells and references a reference sheet, then delivering an output.

In a more specific way, Worksheet "data sheet":
[image]

takes all the "x" cells and then retrieves information using the column headers from row 5 as the key against a reference sheet:

[image]

and output in this format:

[image]

At this point forget about the reference issue, I can't get the worksheet to output correctly. I'm getting a compile error. I'm hoping from there I can get the reference to work.

```
Sub Decentral_Role_Output_Actor_Role()
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim UNameColumn As Integer
Dim RoleColumn As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim counter As Long
counter = 3

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook


Worksheets("Reference Output").Range("A:F").ClearContents
            
               
UNameColumn = 3
RoleColumn = 5
AddRole = 4

'Set column headers
'METADATA|User|CredentialsEmailSent|PersonNumber|Username
'METADATA|UserRole|PersonNumber|AddRemoveRole|RoleCommonName

Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(1, 1) = "METADATA"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(1, 2) = "User"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(1, 3) = "CredentialsEmailSent"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(1, 4) = "PersonNumber"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(1, 5) = "Username"

Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(2, 1) = "METADATA"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(2, 2) = "UserRole"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(2, 4) = "AddRemoveRole"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(2, RoleColumn) = "RoleCommonName"
Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(2, UNameColumn) = "PersonNumber"


For Each Cell In Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("H6:N" & LastRow)
    If Cell.Value = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(counter, UNameColumn).Value = UCase(name)
        Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(counter, RoleColumn) = "ORA_GL"
        Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(counter, 1) = "MERGE"
        Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(counter, 2) = "UserRole"
        Worksheets("Reference Output").Cells(counter, 4) = "ADD"
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
    Next Cell

MsgBox "Role Access Output created at " & myWB.Path



End Sub
```

Like mentioned, I'm getting a compile error.

Result of trying the new script
[Result of new script after changing Reference to "Reference Sheet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ93J.png)

Comment: You wrote for loop "Next Cell" inside the If, move it after closing the End If

Comment: `Range("H:N" & LastRow)` is not a valid range  Should be (eg) `Range("H2:N" & LastRow)`   Also you haven't initialized `counter` so it will start as zero, and `Cells(counter, 1)` isn't valid when counter=0

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the code but it continues to give error on the For Each Cells

I think I initialized the counter with counter = 3, does that note initialize it?

Comment: If you've updated your code then you can edit your question so we can see the current code you're working with...    https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75291324/edit

Comment: @TimWilliams It is now updated. Thanks. Sorry, still getting used to Stack overflow.

Comment: It's useful to include row/column headers in your screenshots if you can, so we can relate the ranges in your code to the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out (untested):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Decentral_Role_Output_Actor_Role()
    
    Const UNameColumn As Long = 3   'use const for fixed values
    Const AddRole As Long = 4
    Const RoleColumn As Long = 5
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsRO As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim name As String, actor As String, secCode, cell As Range
    Dim counter As Long, LastRow As Long, wsRef As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsRO = wb.Worksheets("Reference Output") 'use worksheet references
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Data Sheet")
    Set wsRef = wb.Worksheets("Reference") 'for example
    
    'Column headers
    'METADATA|User|CredentialsEmailSent|PersonNumber|Username
    'METADATA|UserRole|PersonNumber|AddRemoveRole|RoleCommonName
    With wsRO
        .Range("A:F").ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = _
             Array("METADATA", "User", "CredentialsEmailSent", _
                   "PersonNumber", "Username")
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = _
             Array("METADATA", "UserRole", "", "AddRemoveRole", "")
        .Cells(2, UNameColumn).Value = "PersonNumber"
        .Cells(2, RoleColumn).Value = "RoleCommonName"
    End With
        
    'Use a column which will be populated to the last row...
    LastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    counter = 3
    
    For Each cell In wsData.Range("H6:N" & LastRow).Cells
        If UCase(Trim(cell.Value)) = "X" Then 'edited
            
            name = UCase(cell.EntireRow.Columns("F").Value) 'read name from same row
            actor = wsData.Cells(5, cell.Column).Value      'read actor from header row
            secCode = Application.VLookup(actor, wsRef.Range("A2:B5"), 2, False) 'lookup...
            If IsError(secCode) Then secCode = "??????" 'if no match
            
            With wsRO.Rows(counter) 'use a With to reduce code volume
                .Cells(1) = "MERGE"
                .Cells(2) = "UserRole"
                .Cells(UNameColumn).Value = name
                .Cells(counter, 4) = "ADD"
                .Cells(RoleColumn) = secCode
            End With
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    MsgBox "Role Access Output created at " & wb.PATH

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll edit my post to include the output. It didn't error out which is good

Comment: Does the value of `LastRow` look correct? Does the code inside the `If cell.Value = "x" Then` ever get run?  Try putting a breakpoint and stepping through

Comment: I ran the step through on the VBA and it runs the IF statement. However when I mark out the IF statement the result is the exact same. Does that help?

Comment: The `If` always runs - the question is whether the code *inside* the If block runs.  Edited the `If` above to account for x vs X and to trim off spaces.

Comment: It generated the exact same output. Hmmmm. I don't understand you changed the MetaData to with wsRO. Just curious as that output worked before. Might help me understand the script better to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: Difficult for me to debug from here.  If you put a breakpoint on (eg) `name = UCase(...` does the code hit that line when you run it?

Comment: No, it said the code ran successfully.

Comment: You'll get that messagebox regardless of whether the code inside the `If` block runs.

Comment: Then after adding a breakpoint, how do I tell if it hits that line? I thought we were adding the breakpoint to stop the macro from continuing, so therefore the message box wouldn't pop up. Am I approaching it incorrectly?

Comment: Please review https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code and see if that helps

Comment: From what that says the breakpoint should stop the code in it's tracks. Which means if it's in the for loop and not getting stopped then it isn't actually running that loop.
"You can use breakpoints to interrupt the code in a function and check that it is working."

Comment: So for some reason `UCase(Trim(cell.Value)) = "X"` is never True.  If you can share your file I can check it out but I've no idea otherwise...

Comment: There isn't a way to message or share it that I see on StackOverflow. I sent you a connection request on LinkedIn so I can share it.

Comment: OK - replied there

Comment: Sent you a fixed version -check your mail

Comment: It works great! Thank you Tim. I'm embarrassed about the typo and range issues but I'm VERY appreciative of the help.

Comment: No problem - glad it's working for you.